# "Cannot activate already activated outlet" in cordova app on iOS only

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I receive the following error message, running a cordova app on iOS:

> "Cannot activate already activated outlet"

The error is thrown when clicking a button with a `[routerLink]` directive.

[image]

- Angular CLI: 8.1.3
- Angular: 8.1.3
- iOS 13.3

Cordova packages:

```
"cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
"cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.4.5",
```

This is my route definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ScLayoutTopnavigationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/start',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'start',
        component: StartComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'chats',
        component: ChatsComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'chats/:id',
        component: ChatComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'recover-password',
        component: RecoverPasswordComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      },
      {
        path: 'register/:secret',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        data: { title: 's', bodyClasses: ['bot-site'] }
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404'
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20712), however it seems to relate to routing with multiple outlets, which I dont have (I use nested routing, though `<app-root> -> <router-outlet>`.

Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with debugging in Safari. As I can only debug remotely after starting the app on the device, the console misses the output prior to attaching the debugger. I am therefor not sure if there are additional errors thrown before which I might be missing.

What could be causes for the described error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by fixing an unrelated issue that obviously caused the router error subsequently. I missed the error before because I only attached the Safari debugger after initialization of the app and missed it.

I finally researched the tip to refresh the app using the button in Safari Web Inspector which revealed a service throwing an error inside its constructor logic. Fixing this solved the error described in the question.